# Is it fair to use the dupehammer after copy-pasting the duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Is it fair to use the dupehammer after copy-pasting the duplicate answer yourself? I'm referring to this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481882/looking-for-a-data-structure-which-provides-both-random-and-sequential-access), and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34482442/245265).

This seemed really unfair to me. I got the impression that the person in question wanted to get a few upvotes in before locking the question and preventing other folks from answering and contributing (EDIT: whether or not it was the intent, that was the impression I got as a user).

Comment: The word "pointless" jumps to mind first.

Comment: Well, since the accepted answer has absolutely nothing to do with "follow the flow chart" it seems pretty safe to me to unhammer it.  Done.

Comment: Heh, turns out there's a duplicate for this meta-question. :-) I'm okay with this being closed. Hopefully, it'll help the almighty high-rep guys being more careful with their power.

Comment: If they had answered as a community wiki (and the answer was good), I wouldn't mind.